# How to delay action in angular or how to trigger action on reload list

Tags: angular, typescript, list, action

I need to trigger action named `getHowManyItemsOnList()` on my list when i navigate to next node (this app is file explorer). If i did it normally, it run before reload and i getting info about previous page. I need to get info about loaded page and i don't have any idea how. This is how i handling it. After double click on folder, i triggering navigate function:

```
public navigate(element: FileElement): void {
    this.unselectAllItemsOnList();
    if (element.isFolder) {
      this.navigatedDown.emit(element);
      this.topMenu.forEach(item => {
        if (item.action == 'navigate-up')
        {
          item.disabled = false;
        }
      })
    }
  this.getHowManyItemsOnList();
}
```

And what happening in my function:

```
private getHowManyItemsOnList(): void {
    this.itemsCounter = this.fileElements.length;
  }
```

I have two ideas there, but im not sure how to handle it:

First - delay this function asynced and trigger it after page is loaded.
Second - just trigger this function not on navigate, but in something triggering after reload (like ngOnInit).

Somebody has any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to know what you want to achieve without seeing all of the relevant code. Please clarify your requirements, and preferably provide a stackblitz

Comment: It's to big to put in on stackblitz now - i tried it few days ago and i even can't make it work. The simplest way is to trigger action when element has changed on screen, but i don't know how to make it.

Comment: If it's too big to put on stackblitz, then there's definitely too much unseen code in your question. The key to a stackblitz is to abstract the *essence* of your problem into a *simple* demonstration. Can you not do that?

Comment: Ok, i must make weird thing when ngOnChanges didn't work last week. Now it works fine. Thanks for respond.